# PHP, Adding together Arrays that had the same keys. But reindex keys

Tags: php, arrays

So i have two arrays they look something like this

**First array:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 123
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 330
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 234
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 790
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 665
    )
)
```

**Second Array**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 124
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 0330
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 7234
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 0790
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 6665
    )
)
```

So what i would like to do is add them on to each other to look like:

**Both Arrays:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 123
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 330
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 234
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 790
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 665
    )
    [5] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 124
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 0330
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 7234
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 0790
    ) 
    [9] => Array ( 
            [SteamId] => 6665
    )
)
```

But I currently cant get the both array to reindex their keys when adding them. Does somebody know the best way to do this?

Comment: *But I currently cant get the both array to reindex their keys when adding them.*, so where is your attempt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question boils down to *write code for me*, while many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input, expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: `array_merge` & `array_unique` would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply go with [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1,$array2);

print_r($array3);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/960203

***If in-case not worked*** then You need to use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) along with [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$array3 = array_values(array_merge($array1,$array2));

print_r($array3);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/960202

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHP function.

```
$results = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```